# Data decoding initialization/Constructor error handling

Tags: exceptions, initialization

I have a set of loadable data decoders for a specific type of data and a stream to read containing data. Now I want the program to select the correct decoder in a reliable way so I want to use a trial-and-error algorithm. It seems resonable to create a decoder and connect it to the stream using a constructor:

```
// C++ code
// codecs is an array of structs containing function pointers loaded from a dll
FileIn src("foo.wav");
for(size_t i=0; i<N_CODECS; ++i)
    {
    try
        {
        WaveIn wavein(codecs[i],src);
        //Process data
        return;
        }
    catch(...) //Swallow error. It's likly that another codec works. But if it were another error??
        {
        src.reset();
        }
    }
//no codec found (definitly an error)
```

Here, there is probably no true error before we have tried all codecs in the list. The reason to try-catch here is that it is not possible to get return code from the ctor. Would it be better to use zombie objects in this case?

EDIT: What the constructor does, is the following

```
WaveIn::WaveIn(Vtable& vt, FileIn& src):m_vt(vt)
    {
    m_handle=m_vt.create(src);
    if(m_handle==NULL) //Resources allocated in DLL were released in this case.
         {throw "Bad file";}
    }
```

The dtor:

```
WaveIn::~WaveIn()
    {
    m_vt.destroy(m_handle);
    }
```

Comment: This is a religious argument and doesn't have a truly right answer. Both sides have valid points. I prefer to do minimal work in my constructors, especially if that work can fail. If it can fail, if possible, I wouldn't do it in the constructor. In your case, I would either try to find the correct codec prior to instantiating the object and pass it in through the constructor or have a separate method to find the correct codec within the WaveIn class.

Answer (score 1):

Many programmers see [throwing exceptions to control flow as a code smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465953/throwing-exceptions-to-control-flow-code-smell), because Exceptions (in Java, c and C++) are like non-local goto statements that are hard to understand and the chances for memory leaks are high.